# Preferences entry values error - Expected String not array

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences

I am following the documentation for creating my preferences xml, which contains a drop down preference populated with a list of languages. I looked up the documentation, and other questions on Stack Overflow, and I should be able to assign an array of strings for the entryValues property of my preference. However, I keep getting an error that says that a String was expected, not an array.

[image]

[image]

This is my Preferences xml up until now

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<DropDownPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:entries="@array/language_settings_options"
    android:entryValues="@array/locale_language_preference"
    android:key="language_preference"
    android:title="@string/language_settings_title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run the application? This error appears for a ListPreference in my application as well, but it runs and works as expected, so it seems that it's just a bug in the editor

Comment: Interesting, I didn't try running it because I saw the error, just expected it would crash if I run it

Comment: @HåkonSchia yes you're right, it runs alright, must be a bug just like you said. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!